# Functions about Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I recently took over an Excel file. And now I try to modify the VBA codes at the back end. I cannot find Ceiling_Math function in Excel, can anybody tell me where to find the details of this function?

[image]

I cannot find the details anywhere.

Comment: Its built into Excel => https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj231868(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: You can right click a function/method name and select *Definition* and you will either be taken to the VBA source code if its a user function or the Object Browser which will how you where it actually lives.

Comment: Hello Alex I just used Definition but it showed Identifier under cursor is not recognized .... how should I do?

Comment: @BarryWang this is **not** a function that you will be able to modify.

Comment: Identifier Not Recognized with Excel versions 2010 and prior. This function added in Excel 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Ceiling_Math](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheetfunction.ceiling_math.aspx) is a rounding function that, when used with multiple arguments, lets you round up to multiples.

However in the example you gave, it appears to be only using only one argument, so I assume there is a default behaviour that means: round up to the nearest integer.

If that is the use case, consider switching it for the [Excel ROUNDUP function](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/ROUNDUP-function-f8bc9b23-e795-47db-8703-db171d0c42a7).